# Three color gradient scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I want color a scatterplot with 3 colors which correspond to 3 categories, but use a gradient with the mix of three colors which are based on the categories.  The data is 2D (x1 and x2) and each point belongs to one of three categories with some probability.  The dataframe below contains the points (x1, x2), the category (cat), the probability of being in that category (membership), and the probability of each in each of the three categories (prob1,prob2,prob3).  The membership probability is the highest of the three that I separated out to easily categorize the data.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gunsnfloyd/algorithmdata/main/fuzzy.tsv

I can color the three points no problem. This works.

```
ggplot(data = fuzzy.df, aes(x = x1, y = x2, color = as.factor(cat)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "blue", "red"))
```

[image]

I tried this using the membership as a defining variable for color, but it does not differentiate by category.
[image]
ggplot(data = fuzzy.df, aes(x = x1, y = x2, color = membership))+
geom_point()+
scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(3))

I want to be able to fade the colors based on their probabilities but differentiate by the category.  How do I combine these concepts in ggplot?

Answer (score 2):

I think this brings you close. It's an adaption from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362548/20002111).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x1, y = x2)) +
  geom_point(data = d1, aes(group = cat, colour = membership)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c('red', 'red4'), 
                        name = "hp = 1") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data = d2, aes(group = cat, colour = membership)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c('lightblue', 'darkblue'), 
                        name = "hp = 2") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data = d3, aes(group = cat, colour = membership)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c('lightgreen','darkgreen'), 
                        name = "hp = 3")
```

gives

[image]

Data:

```
library(readr)
fuzzy.df <- 
  readr::read_tsv(file =
                    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gunsnfloyd/algorithmdata/main/fuzzy.tsv")
d1 <- fuzzy.df[fuzzy.df$cat == "1", ]
d2 <- fuzzy.df[fuzzy.df$cat == "2", ]
d3 <- fuzzy.df[fuzzy.df$cat == "3", ]
```

Comment: For KNN or PCA, it could be a very nice type of representation!

Comment: I see! I was trying to do more than ggplot can do.  So make three separate plots each with a different color gradient and them merge them.  This will highlight the strength of membership.    Thanks!  I'm still going to tinker around with this to see if there is a way to merge the colors.